# About a consonant between 2 vowels, "/ˈteɪ·lər/" or "/ˈteɪl·ər/"?

Tags: pronunciation, consonants

I found this rule in dictionary.

If a consonant is between 2 vowels, then a delimiter is put after the consonant if the previous vowel is strong & but a delimiter is not put after the consonant if the following vowel is strong.

Ex: Lemon **/ˈlem.ən/** (see the delimiter be put after **/m/**) ([Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lemon))

But Delicious **/dɪˈlɪʃ.əs/** ([Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/delicious)) & we don't have **/dɪl.ˈɪʃ.əs/**

But Tailor **/ˈteɪ·lər/** does not apply that rule because it has a diphthong **/eɪ/**  [Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tailor?a=american-english)

But if you hear **Tailor** in [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tailor_1?q=tailor), you will find it sounds like **/ˈteɪl·ər/**

So pronounce it as "**/ˈteɪ·lər/**" (hear the sound at [Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tailor?a=american-english)) or "**/ˈteɪl·ər/**" (hear the sound at [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tailor_1?q=tailor))?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/599686/2085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may depend on the person, or on how you choose to analyze English syllabification (which is a dubious and contentious matter). I believe there are some people who argue that "lemon" should be split up as /ˈlɛ.mən/ and "delicious" as /dɪˈlɪ.ʃəs/, because of general principles of syllabification such as avoiding onsetless syllables or maximizing the onset.

In the specific case of the word "tailor," I feel that ***I*** pronounce it, at least on some level, as /ˈteɪl.ər/, because I smooth the phoneme /eɪ/, which is usually a rising diphthong, to a monophthong or perhaps a falling dipthong: [ˈteɫɚ] or [ˈteə̯ɫɚ]. This smoothing does not occur for me in words like *playlist, grayly,* or *rayless.* The easiest way I see to explain this contrast is by different syllabification of the intervocalic /l/ in these words: /ˈteɪl.ər/ vs. /ˈgreɪ.li/. But other analyses are possible.*

There are other types of allophony that may occur in other accents exclusively before tautosyllabic /l/.
John Wells has a post about vowel backing in British English accents that occurs in this position: "[newly minimal](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/newly-minimal.html)". He says

> Christian Uffmann reports an interesting development that he has observed in 18-year-old applicants for university places at Sussex. He asked them whether *ruler* (king) and *ruler* (for measuring or drawing straight lines) are homonyms or not. The unanimous opinion was that they are not homonyms, because they are pronounced differently. (So technically they would be homographs.)
>
> This is because in southeastern England /uː/ has developed two very distinct allophones: a truly back [uː] before tautosyllabic (or stem-final) /l/, but a fronted quality approaching [yː] in other positions. The kingly ruler, **ˈruːlə**, is taken as transparently bimorphemic, rule#(e)r, so retains the back uː of rule; but the measuring ruler, **ˈryːlə**, has lost touch with its origins and is taken as an unanalysable unit, with a corresponding clear l and fronted vowel **yː**.

This means that there might be variation between speakers in the pronunciation of "tailor" depending on whether they analyze it as a morphologically simple or morphologically complex. Etymologically, the word did come into English as a whole from French *taillour/eur,* but its status as a noun of occupation may increase the likelihood that speakers analyze the final *-or* as a synchronic suffix (even though the base "tail" is not ususally used as a corresponding verb). I don't know if there are any speakers who don't rhyme "tailor" with "nailer" (one who nails), but it seems at least possible.

#### *The contrast for me between "tailor" and "grayly" doesn't *have* to be explained in terms of syllabification

As I said, to me it feels like the first syllable of "tailor" is "tail", with coda /l/. However, an alternative analysis could be that in my accent, vowel smoothing and l-"darkening" are word-level processes and /l/ is darkened when it is in non-foot-initial position at the word level, regardless of whether it is in the syllable coda or the syllable onset (for more elaboration of this kind of analysis, see "[An amphichronic approach to English syllabification](http://www.bermudez-otero.com/amphichronic.pdf)", Ricardo Bermúdez-Otero, 2013). Compare t-lenition, which does not occur foot-initially at the word level, but which does apply foot-medially, not only after "short" vowels but also after "long" or "strong" vowels—as in the word "waiting" [weɪt̬ɪŋ], which would be syllabified according to the rule that you have learned as /weɪ.tɪŋ/.

Comment: Or with _tailer_ (someone who drives too close behind you), for that matter… ;-)  Generally speaking, though, I'd say most speakers do not distinguish /teɪ.lər/ and /teɪl.ər/ at all, so they wouldn't be able to answer the question. Certainly I have no idea where I syllabify the word.